# Batch find and replace text in multiple PDFs

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

Ive got a folder with 100's of 1 page PDFs.

The PDFs all have a footer in them, in which there is a typo.

I want to essentially run a batch find and replace across all the PDFs to fix the typo.

I do not have the original source files the PDFs where generated from, but i do have Adobe Acrobat Pro DC (latest version) as part of creative cloud.

Is there any way i can do this, using Acrobat or other software ?

Ive found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9s2h2t288zs) on a work around, but for 100s of PDFs this would involve too much manual work.

Comment: Couldn't you combine the PDFs first into one document, then do the search and replace, then extract each page as a separate PDF?

Comment: Thanks Billy, i think thats the solution ! Write it as an answer and i will accept it

Comment: OK, I have now done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no Acrobat expert but a quick perusal of the features of Acrobat DC shows it should be possible to combine the PDFs into one document, then do a search and replace, then extract each page as a separate PDF.  Try that.